# WPF animation first run

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a simple WPF application that contains a user control that is animated in and out by a pair of storyboards on the main window.  I am animating the user control's opacity, scaletransform.scalex and scaletransform.scaley to pop it in and out of view.  It looks cool except for the first time it runs.  The animation is set to take 3/10 of a second, though I have increased this during my testing.  I've tried setting a default value at a fraction of a second in to see if there is a problem where the values of the properties I'm animating aren't defaulting as expected.  That did nothing.  I even explicitly call my "hide" animation on window loaded to see if this would help me set my default values, but that didn't work either.  Is there some initialization that the runtime is doing the first time I fire the animation?  Is there a way I can explicitly call that kind of initialization before showing the UI?  The symptom is that the control isn't even visible until about 2/10 of a second into the first animation.  Sometimes it's longer and the control shows up after it's been fully animated (opacity and size are their final values when it finally shows up).

Comment: When/how is the first animation being triggered?  Also, from the symptoms you described it sounds like the opacity may be changing at a different rate / after the scale transforms.

Comment: The first animation is being triggered as all animations are, through a mouse click.  I do this in the code behind so I can mark the event as handled if needed.  The opacity works fine in all other animations as well.  Basically, there is no difference in the code between the first animation and any other animation.  What I was wondering is if the WPF runtime is optimizing something (my control is hidden by ScaleTransform and Opacity by default), and this is the price I pay for some automatic memory optimization or something.

Comment: As if the WPF runtime says "oh, this control isn't viewable right off the bat since the ScaleTransforms and the Opacity is 0, let's load this dynamically later", and as a result it plays catchup while I'm expecting it to isntantly animate itself into view.

Comment: It shouldn't be caused by that. I can make a similar sample work with 2000 controls in a grid and the initial animation from ScaleX,ScaleY,Opacity=0 without any lag in the animation.

Comment: I'm defaulting everything and debugging to make sure the values I'm animating are where they need to be when the app loads.  The only other non-trivial thing I'm doing right before calling the animation is setting the DataContext of the UserControl.  The UserControl has a handful of child UserControl's (that inherit the DataContext by default) and there is a lot of binding going on.  Is there a lot of initialization overhead with this process that could be causing the window to delay its rendering the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're setting the DataContext of the UserControl right before the animation. Presumably you have binding going on, which is creating visual objects and adding them to the visual tree at the same time the animation is supposed to start. This requires processing that the animation is fighting for. The way to avoid this is to have the control instantiated (with DataContext set), but hidden, so the visual object creation does not need to be performed at the time of animation. (via my co-worker Tim Lee)

Comment: Okay, you're absolutely right...and this was my initial hunch as well.  However, the runtime is trying to be too smart for it's own good.  If I try any which way to hide it from view (opacity, negative margin, scaletransform, translatetransform), it does the same thing.  If I allow it to be viewable, I don't even need to set the DataContext first...the first animation goes smoothly.  It's almost as if I need to trick the runtime into thinking it's viewable when it's actually not.  That, or I need to know how to explicitly tell it to build the visual tree.  The latter feels less hacky.

Comment: I understand this thread is ancient, but how did you end up resolving this matter? Even setting the respective controls to 1 width didn't help. I'm relatively new to WPF and therefore didn't get any hidden cues between the lines here.